# VBA: Finding and replacing Word references out of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

I am trying to find and replace Microsoft Word referneces by executing a macro out of Microsoft Excel. So far I managed the following which works fine when executed in Word but returns a runtime error '450' out of Excel.

```
Sub changeName()

  Dim wdPath As String
  Dim wdApp As Object
  Dim wdDoc As Object

  'Get the path to the Word document out of Excel
  wdPath = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2,3)

  Set wdApp = CreateObject(Word.Application)
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wdPath)


  'Doing some stuff with the bookmarks, not touching wdApp

  Call findAndReplace(wdApp)

End Sub


Sub findAndReplace(wdApp)

  'first try: runtime error 450
  With Selection.Find

  'second try: runtime error 91
  With wdApp.Selection.Find

    .ClearFormating
    .Text = "test"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    Do While .Execute
      Selection.Delete

      Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Textmarke", ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, _ 
      ReferenceItem:="1234", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeperateNumbers:=False, _
      SeperatorString:=" "
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

I think the problem is that the Excel sees the Selection-method as its own and not as the one from Word. However I have not found any way to solve this.

I am using Word 2010 and Excel 2010.

I really hope somone has an idea how to solve this.

Comment: wdApp.Selection

Comment: ^^ when using multi-application programs, always qualify objects (which are not part of the "main" application) with which application they are referring to

Comment: Sadly that does not do the trick. When adding `wdApp` it results in a runtime error 91

Comment: The problem is with your declarations. The code you published doesn't show any declarations. So, how can one find the error? Best practice: post a complete procedure.

Comment: Apart from the bits where you are declaring your objects, etc, that @Variatus requested, you may also need to include in the posted code the bits where you are opening the document, etc.  There might be something in that bit which is causing the issue (e.g. if you aren't opening the document correctly then it won't be able to select any text).

Comment: I am sorry for not doing it right away. I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should have the declarations correctly - untested though. I also didn't check your code for functionality.

```
Sub ChangeName()

  Dim wdPath As String
  Dim wdApp As Word.Application
  Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

  'Get the path to the Word document out of Excel
  wdPath = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 3)

  Set wdApp = CreateObject(Word.Application)
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wdPath)


  'Doing some stuff with the bookmarks, not touching wdApp

  Call FindAndReplace(wdDoc)

End Sub


Sub FindAndReplace(wdApp As wdDoc As Word.Document)

    Dim Rng As Word.Range

    Set Rng = wdDoc.Content
    With Rng.Find
        .ClearFormating
        .Text = "test"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop

        Do While .Execute
            Rng.Delete
            Rng.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Textmarke", _
                                     ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, _
                                     ReferenceItem:="1234", _
                                     InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                     IncludePosition:=False, _
                                     SeperateNumbers:=False, _
                                     SeperatorString:=" "
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
However I still get a runtime error 91 for the line `Set Rng = wdApp.Selection.Range`

Comment: Hmmm. That's because there is no selection in the just opened document. That would mean that (a) you don't need to pass WdApp to FindAndReplace as a parameter and (b) you need to find another way of defining the range you wish to search, perhaps `Set Rng = wdDoc.Content`. I have made these change in the above solution.